# Using string methods on unsigned char * without casting

Tags: c

I noticed I've used several string methods like

```
strcpy(userAmount, pch);
```

on `unsigned char*` buffers, **without** casting. e.g., these variables are defined like

```
   u8 * pch = NULL;
   u8 userAmount[255] = {0};
```

It has worked fine so far.

Is it expected behaviour? Shall I continue using it this way?

So far buffer stored ASCII text, it may hold UTF8 in the future - will things be different in this case (e.g., in terms of casting, buffer type)?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: When using library functions use the types they epxect. For the `str*()` family of functions this is `char` as per the C-Standard.

Comment: The thing with UTF-8 is that it's really a byte-centric encoding, just like "normal" characters in modern computers. So an array of `char` (signed or unsigned) will work fine no matter if the contents is pure ASCII (which is a subset of UTF-8) or an UTF-8 encoded string.

Comment: As for signed/unsigned characters, the "signedness" of the `char` type is up to the implementation. It may be that the code you've seen is all compiled with a compiler where `char` is unsigned?

Comment: @alk: I prefer unsigned byte arrays to represent data which may hold binary data and also maybe string so it is more convenient for me. That is why I am interesting if using those methods I mentioned above the way I wrote is ok - like I said, it has been working fine so far

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I am not sure I'd have to check if `char` is signed or not on that compiler (how?). PS. If it were signed, the code I wrote above wasn't supposed to work?

Comment: Some compilers give an error if you pass `unsigned char *` to `strcpy` etc, and some don't. It's a bit of a pain; I tend to end up making my functions that operate on byte buffers to take `void *`, in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use some non-standard type (`u8`?) when a standard type (`char`) would do?

However, your approach should be ok.

From the C11-Standard (*italics* by me):

> **7.24.1 String function conventions**
>
> The header string.h declares one type and several functions, and defines one
>   macro useful for manipulating arrays of character type *and other objects treated as arrays
>   of character type*.
>
> [...]
>
> For all functions in this subclause, each character *shall be interpreted as if it had the type
>   unsigned char* (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a
>   different value).

Comment: and it still works even if on my platform char is signed or unsigned? (like Joachim Pileborg noted)

Comment: Regarding the functions declared in `<string.h>`: If it mattered, the implementation your are using did not comform to the C-Standard. @dmcr_code

Comment: ok so I am fine in my approach in any case (even if char is signed or unsigned) assuming I use C standard compliant implementation

Comment: I use `unsigned char` for byte data that does not represent a string. Since it doesn't have negative values, it behaves nicer with arithmetic, and everything is well-define (working with signed integral types often has implementation-defined or undefined behaviour).   `unsigned char` is a pain to type everywhere, so it's OK to have a typedef such as `byte` or `u8`.

Comment: @alk: So is it ok to pass `unsigned char` pointer to `strcpy` *without* a cast?